# Configuring angular application to run in container with nginx always results in the nging index.tml being served

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, nginx

I have a simple Angular application and I am trying to containerize it using Docker and an nginx image. (What I think I do is ) I first use a node-alpine image to build the files, then an nginx image for the actual work of serving them. I have never used nginx before and I am new to Docker, I was following a tutorial, but unfortunately when I opened my container, it launched the localhost address and the nginx welcome page was served. When I go to localhost/index.html however, my angular index.html is served, so I assume my mistake is somewhere in the nginx.conf file, because when I run my angular app simply with ng serve, the correct index.html is served yet again. On the other hand, when I inspect the file system in my container, the index.html file in the /usr/share/nginx/html is my Angular one, so I am very confused.

I am attaching my configuration:

.dockerignore:

```
.git
.editorconfig
/.vscode/*
/node_modules
/e2e
/docs
.gitignore
*.zip
/dist
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:18.18-alpine3.18 as build

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN npm ci
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:latest
COPY --from=build /app/dist/dev-ops-frontend /usr/share/nginx/html
```

nginx.conf

```
events{}

http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types; 

    server {        
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;

        index index.html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if relevant, but I am also attaching the angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "DevOpsFrontend": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/dev-ops-frontend",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "DevOpsFrontend:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "DevOpsFrontend:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "DevOpsFrontend:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  }
}
```

An odd thing that I noticed in the tutorial was that when I enter the command "ng build", my files are actually in /dist/dev-ops-frontend/browser, not just /dist/dev-ops-frontend. I thought the tutorial might be outdated, so I generated a new project, but when I went on with building it, the result files were in /dist/new-project, without the browser directory.

What I've tried so far:

-I played around with the directories in the dockerfile, trying COPY --from=build /app/dist/dev-ops-frontend/browser /usr/share/nginx/html, which didn't work, then COPY --from=build /app/dist/dev-ops-frontend /usr/share/nginx/html, with the same results.

-I looked in other threads about nginx.conf configurations, moving the `root /usr/share/nginx/html` under the location block, but that still didn't solve my issue.

-I tried creating a new default project, used the same dockerfile and ran it - and the correct index.html was served! Then, I copied the src directory from my old project to the new one, rebuilt the image - now it served the default nginx index file again... I then returned the old src folder and rebuilt but guess what, it still returned the nginx index file ( Although maybe it was just cached... but I think I built the container with --no-cache, so I am not entirely sure )

-I also tried entirely removing the location / block from the configuration file, still did not quite work.

I apologize because I saw this question asked many times, but none of the proposed solutions there worked for me ( or I guess I am not experienced enough to interpret them properly )

Comment: Which Angular version?

Comment: The original Angular app with the browser folder in the dist was Angular 17, the other test app I made was using Angular 16. Node version is 18 using nvm if that's relevant

Comment: files are in '/dist/dev-ops-frontend/browser" becaue you are using `:application` builder. it is considered up to date and future thing, so you'd want to use this one in most cases.